# How can i cancel or update an saga polling request with same action call

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, saga

I am polling api with delay and cancellation using race condition.

What i want to achieve is when my page renders, i want to start polling for scores and on some action i will call same polling (same api) with some other query params so that i just want to update the same polling with new params.

for that i have done something like this.

```
export function* pollScoreSnippets() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const { data } = yield call(() => request(apis.GET_SCORE_API));
      yield put({
        type: types.DASHBOARD_DATA_FETCHED,
        payload: {
          type: ['scores'],
          data: {
            scores: { values: data.data },
          },
        },
      });
      yield call(delay, SCORE_SNIPPET_POLLING_DELAY);
    } catch (err) {
      yield put({
        type: types.DASHBOARD_DATA_FETCHING_ERROR,
        payload: {
          error: err.response.data,
        },
      });
      yield call(delay, SCORE_SNIPPET_POLLING_DELAY + 10);
    }
  }
}

export function* watchPollSaga() {
  while (true) {
    // console.log('watching');
    yield take(types.POLL_SCORE_SNIPPETS);
    yield race([call(dashGenerators.pollScoreSnippets), take(types.STOP_POLLING_SCORE_SNIPPETS)]);
  }
}
```

That is working for me but with this approach i have to call cancel action then again same action for restarting polling again.

Is there any way that if i will call same action and either it will update the current polling request or cancel or restart with new polling request

something kind of:

```
export function* watchPollSaga() {
  while (true) {
    // console.log('watching');
    yield take(types.POLL_SCORE_SNIPPETS);
    yield race([call(dashGenerators.pollScoreSnippets), take(types.POLL_SCORE_SNIPPETS)]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you succeed ? I'm kind of looking for the same...

Comment: @Mayoul not yet i am using race only.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but wouldn't `takeLatest` do the trick? `export function* watchPollSaga() { yield takeLatest(types.POLL_SCORE_SNIPPETS, dashGenerators.pollScoreSnippets); }`

Comment: in that case how will you stop ??